# Date +/- Function PHP

Tags: php, function, datetime

I am trying make a function that checks whether the date is a holiday or not. Such as, someone on 24/02/2016 added two days, then the function set the date as 28/02/2016. Because 26 & 27 February is holiday (in Bangladesh). I have been trying make it but did not get any way. Can someone suggest, how to do this task with PHP?

Comment: Take a look at the DateTime class http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: How are holidays defined?

Comment: This is the code to define the holidays:
`public static function CheckIfBusinessDay($date)
{
        $timestamp = strtotime($date);
        $day = strtolower(date('l', $timestamp));

        return !in_array($day, Yii::app()->params['weekends']);
    }`

Comment: So are you trying to make (1) a function that determines if a day is a holiday, (2) a function that determines if a day is a weekend, or (3) a function that can add days, but skip over days that satisfy (1) or (2)?  And you should [edit] your code into your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way in PHP to handle dates is [Carbon PHP](http://carbon.nesbot.com/)

You could do something like that

```
Carbon::createFromDate(2016, 2, 24)->addDays(2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a good and easy way. But the problem is that I have to make it with raw PHP.

Comment: What do you mean "raw PHP"?

Comment: I mean, I have to handle it with written PHP code. I cannot use any API of framwork.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a vanilla php solution, use DataTime class

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2006-12-12');
$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks...I am looking this kind of thing. Thank you.